# discord.py save every message in specific channel (using channel id)

Tags: discord.py

How can a python bot read every message that is sent in a certain channel or read every message that was sent in one using a command like `$save 421345187663708161`. Thanks in advance, havent been able to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Instead of looking for an answer already why don't you try to code it yourself?

Comment: I don't have much experience with discord.py in this specific catagory and as stated in my question:"havent been able to find the answer anywhere."

Comment: I really doubt anyone is gonna answer this, it's a wishlist, not a programming question at all. StackOverflow has never been a tutoring service, a homework completion service, or a code writing service, this is abundantly clear in both the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Oh well my bad then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this in an `on_message` Function which scans the message content for "$save" on the beginning, then gets the channel per the given ID.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("$save"):
        splittedcontent = message.content.split()
        
        channel = client.get_channel(splittedcontent[1])
        all_messages = channel.history()
```

What your job now is, is to understand this code, maybe inform about the things that are going on here (like channel.history) and implement this to your code (preferably also with some try/except cases).